# Exact meaning of "sooner"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the exact meaning of "**sooner**" in the following passage? Does it mean premature?

The text is excerpt of a political telegram:

> I stated to Beeley that I had not consulted him **sooner** as it had been my impression that as a result of conversations between us over the past year I felt that his Government was aware of the fact.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

In this use, [sooner](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sooner) means earlier, or before now, rendering:

> ... I had not consulted him before now, as ...